# program install via ubuntu software centre

Tags: music-player

I am running ubuntu 13.04 and when I tried to install vkaudio via the software centre I do not get the install option on the right hand side.

Comment: I am afraid 13.04 is off topic and EOL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this application is free the license is listed as proprietary, so in order to install it you need to click on 'more info' and then 'buy' (and then log in using your Ubuntu One account credentials).